# How can I change the default generator for routes in Rails 7 when using scaffolding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator

I'm doing some changes in the default behavior of generator scaffold and I want to change the routes format.

When we run `rails g scaffold Post title mesage` the file `routes.rb` returns this:

```
resource :posts
```

But I want this:

```
resources :posts do
  collection do
    delete :destroy_selected
  end
end
```

I already saw that this is at file `railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/generators/rails/resource_route/resource_route_generator.rb`, but I don't know how I can do the change inside my project.

Answer (score 1):

10 minutes after I did another test and it worked!

Here is the solve:

```
// lib/generators/rails/scaffold_controller_generator.rb

require 'rails/generators/rails/resource_route/resource_route_generator'

module Rails
  module Generators
    class ResourceRouteGenerator < NamedBase
      def add_resource_route
        return if options[:actions].present?
        route "resources :#{file_name.pluralize} do\n  collection do\n    delete :destroy_selected\n  end\nend", namespace: regular_class_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```